# React native: invaild source for image when source is a formatted string retrived from Firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have saved following image source along with uri in firebase as a string

```
coverImage " uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570102881689-c04ab4cf1f4c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDF8Ym84alFLVGFFMFl8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60"
```

along with other attributes such as title extra. when i am passing the prop in the Image source the following error shows

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type [number].
```

following is the image prop.

```
<Image style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }} source={`{${item.image}}`} />
```

I have consoled.log the **item.image** and the link is working fine in when I **ctrl+click** on it.
Any feedback as to what I am doing wrong.

---

In console.log I get the following result

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": "al1tT6JfNYssimYZ8Lhy",
    "image": " uri: \"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570102881689-c04ab4cf1f4c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDF8Ym84alFLVGFFMFl8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60\"",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum",
  },
]
```

and console.log the item.image when I render it through the flatlist following is the result.

```
uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570102881689-c04ab4cf1f4c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDF8Ym84alFLVGFFMFl8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried this? `<Image source={{ uri: item.image }} />`

Comment: Yes,but output remain the same

Comment: What do you receive when you console.log(item.image)?

Comment: I just updated the question a bit, please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: hey Rayan your answer was correct there was a issue in my formatting of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [URI](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image) as shown below:

```
<Image style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
```

Also the `image` field in the object seems to be prefixed with `uri:`, try setting an URL starting with `https://`.

Comment: With this the error is not there but image is also not visible

Comment: Can you give some more context on 'not visible'? Also try restarting dev server.  The `item.image` is valid URl right ?

Comment: I just updated the question a bit, please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Is ` uri: \` actually part of `image` field in Firestore? You can just store image URL starting with `https://` ?

Comment: Hey man solved it. With your update to format I has to go and remove uri keyword from database along with quotes. Thanks man